# nuxt.js - unable to define host and port

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

nuxt.js always defaults to `localhost` despite host being defined as `frontend.gradez.loc`  in `nuxt.config.js`

Contents of `nuxt.config.js`:

```
server: {
  host: 'frontend.gradez.loc',
  port: 3000
},
```

Contents of `package.json`:

```
"config": {
  "nuxt": {
    "host": "frontend.gradez.loc",
    "port": "3000"
  }
}
```

`nuxt` launch script as `dev`:

```
"dev": "nuxt --hostname frontend.gradez.loc --port 3000",
```

For some odd reason when starting the development script it always defaults to: `Listening on: http://localhost:3000/`

I tried to do exactly the same on react and the only thing I had to do was create a `.env` file and inside it I added `host=frontend.gradez.loc` and it worked just like that.

Comment: i dont think it has meaningful reason

Comment: @MdMahamudulHasan It does if you're backend isn't running on localhost and you need cookies with the `SameSite` attribute.

Comment: Have you tried other options as well mentioned here: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/?

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH Yes I've tried all the options

Comment: I tried few things. I only edited the package.json file as this: "dev": "NUXT_HOST=testportal.com NUXT_PORT=3333 nuxt". On trying to run the project its giving "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 43.255.154.26:3000". It seems it tried to do what its expected to do. This error is genuine I just tried, I don't have any address like this.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH Yeah but the address I choose is available. It's working in React, why wouldn't it work in Nuxt? They almost exactly use the same setup for this.

Comment: Can you please go through this link for once https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/490? It might be helpful it seems.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH I don't have problems with changing the `port` just with the `host`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create your server, under the hood Nuxt uses Node's `http.createServer`, then calls `listen({ host, port })` on that server.

So if on your local machine the hostname `frontend.gradez.loc` is mapped to `127.0.0.1`, which I assume is the case, then that server is running on the IP `127.0.0.1`.

To create the url you see printed in `Listening on...`, Nuxt gets the IP of that underlying server, and maps it back to a hostname string. It statically maps the IP `127.0.0.1` to the string `'localhost'`, so no matter what `host` you configure, if it maps to `127.0.0.1` then Nuxt will always map that to `localhost` in that url. The code that does this is [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/1fda184990430d81dc8dfc11fca35236e39d449e/packages/server/src/listener.js#L48).

There's nothing incorrect *per-se* about reporting the server is running on `localhost:3000` rather than `frontend.gradez.loc:3000`. It's literally true, in a networking sense, because both ultimately point to `127.0.0.1:3000`. So nothing is broken here from the perspective of the dev server, it's working as designed.

I'm not sure if you have anything automatically loading that url in the browser when you start the server - if so I can see how this is inconvenient from the perspective of other things in your workflow coupled to that hostname such as cookies, proxy servers etc - but if you manually type `frontend.gradez.loc:3000` into your browser everything will just work.