# Nuxt3 tries to start on the host, not in the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am running nuxt3 on a remote server in docker-compose, but in the logs the server is trying to start outside the container (it is possible that I am wrong). `95.183.11.176` this is the ip address of my server. Why is this happening? How can I get nuxt to deploy a server in a container?

```
frontend-nuxt3        | > nuxt-app@1.0.10 start-development
frontend-nuxt3        | > nuxt start --hostname 0.0.0.0 
frontend-nuxt3        | [nitro] [uncaughtException] Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 95.183.11.176:3000
frontend-nuxt3        |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1446:21)
frontend-nuxt3        |     at listenInCluster (node:net:1511:12)
frontend-nuxt3        |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1660:7)
frontend-nuxt3        |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:111:8) {
frontend-nuxt3        |   code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
frontend-nuxt3        |   errno: -99,
frontend-nuxt3        |   syscall: 'listen',
frontend-nuxt3        |   address: '95.183.11.176',
frontend-nuxt3        |   port: 3000
frontend-nuxt3        | }
```

I tried changing the port to 3001, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the same error.
Also tried `fuser --kill 3000/tcp`. And add config to package.json:

```
"config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 3000
  }
```

My configuration file:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

COPY ./package*.json /app/

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  nuxt3:
    image: username/frontend_nuxt3:latest
    container_name: nuxt3
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3750:3000"
    command: start-development
```

piece of package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start-development": "nuxt start --hostname 0.0.0.0",
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with docker. Its how `nuxt` works. Found few resources with quick googling https://stackoverflow.com/q/62719805/7857701 and https://nuxtjs.ir/faq/host-port .

In hostname you have to specify a host. If you want to set an ip like `0.0.0.0` follow the doc